# How to grab the previous hour of a timestamp(4) with TIMEZONE column?

Tags: sql, oracle

so I have a table called Value. I am trying to derive the Value for the last hour (***HR --> Timestamp(4) with TIME ZONE*** ) so that I can use it in a conditional statement in this Stored Procedure that I'm building. However, when i try the following, Oracle only returns a Date (**01-Jan-19**) rather than the previous hour (**01-Jan-19 01.00.00.00000000 AM UTC**). What am I doing wrong?

```
select hr
     , hr - (1/24) as Converted
 from value;
```

If I try the following, I return '**31-DEC-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM**' as the value for 'Converted' (no matter what the value for HR is):

```
select hr
     , to_timestamp(hr - (1/24)) as converted
   from value;
```

Which ultimately will be used as the definition of a variable in my stored procedure:

```
 select max(value) 
   into v_Previous_hour
   from value
  where hr = hr - (1/24);
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running this in sqlplus or some other oracle client?  What is your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter set to?

Comment: from the Oracle SQL Developer console. the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter is just set at default ( i didn't alter my session)

Comment: The date still has a time, the client just isn't showing it to you - because of the NLS setting. What data type do you actually want to end up with; what will your PL/SQL variable be declared as, and does it need to keep the original time zone? (Probably, if you will be using it later to query against the same table).

Comment: I doubt that you **always** get `31-DEC-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM` for `hr - (1/24) as Converted` no matter what the value for HR is

Comment: What do you mean by "grab the previous hour"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select hr
     , cast( hr - (1/24) as timestamp) as Converted
 from value;
```

Also, the query below is not going to do what you think it is.

```
 select max(value) 
   into v_Previous_hour
   from value
  where hr = hr - (1/24);
```

Comment: This converts to a date, then to a timestamp: so you lose fractional seconds and time zone information. Which may be OK for what the OP needs...

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(HR) AS HR,
       TO_CHAR(CAST(HR - INTERVAL '1' HOUR - INTERVAL '0.233' SECOND AS TIMESTAMP(4) WITH TIME ZONE)) AS HR_MINUS_ONE_HOUR
  FROM VAL;
```

(Here I subtracted an additional 0.233 seconds just to make sure we were dealing with timestamps, per @AlexPoole's comment on @OldProgrammer's answer).

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa9f6/6)

Comment: When I tried it without the cast it returned more than 4 digits right of the decimal, so apparently some variety of conversion is going on. It's Oracle, it's date/time related - who's to know? :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Oracle only returns a Date (01-Jan-19)

A date still has a time, your client just isn't showing it to you. You can use `to_char()` to display it explicitly:

```
select to_char(hr - (1/24), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from ...
```

It is a date because [that's the result of timestamp - number] arithmetic, and the timestamp is implicitly converted to a date before the subtraction. But you are losing both the fractional seconds *and* the time zone from your original value. Even if you cast back to a plain timestamp that information isn't recovered, and if you cast back to a timestamp with time zone it imolicitly picks up the current session's time zone, so won't necessarily match.

To keep both you can do what you suggested in your answer, or

```
select hr - interval '1' hour from ...
```

In your procedure, declare a variable of the same data type, e.g. (as an nonymous block):

```
declare
  l_hr value.hr%type;
begin
  select hr - interval '1' hour
  into l_hr
  from value
  where ... ;

  ...
end;
```

Don't be tempted to store or manipulate the value as a string, keep it as its origial data type. It will be easieer to work with, safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this table [Matrix of Datetime Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492)

When you perform `{TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE} - {NUMERIC}` then you get `DATE` value, i.e. you loose the time zone information.

Better use INTERVAL, e.g. `hr - INTERVAL '1' HOUR` or `hr - NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'HOUR')`

Anyway, I don't understand your question. If you ask "*How to grab the previous hour of a timestamp(4) with TIMEZONE column?*" then my answer would be

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM hr - INTERVAL '1' HOUR) AS Solution_1
    TO_CHAR(hr - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'HH24')  AS Solution_2
FROM ...
```

Note, solution `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM hr - INTERVAL '1' HOUR)` always returns the hour of UTC time, whereas `TO_CHAR(hr - INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'HH24')` returns hour from the stored time zone.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours of hairpulling (and ironically after OldProgrammer was nice enough to provide me with an answer), I found a workaround:

```
 select hr
      , hr - numtodsinterval(1, 'hour') as converted
   from value;
```

Comment: Or `hr - interval '1' hour`, as in your earlier question *8-)

Comment: i'm confused :( were my questions duplicates?

Comment: Not really, but you could have applied what I did there with the string value here too.

Comment: what happens if I want to use hr - interval '1' hour or hr - numtods... (etc.) in a where clause. what would be the proper way to do it? so for example, i want to grab the row that is correlated to the HR that is one hour behind the actual one. (HR - 1)

Comment: The same, but you can't do `where hr = hr - interval '1' hour` or any of the equivalents; as OldProgrammer hinted that isn't right. A single value of `hr` cannot be equal to itself an hour ago. You said you were putting `he - interval '`' hour` into a variable, so then you could do `where hr = your_variable`. It depends what your overall goal is though, it isn't very clear why you're doing this. It's also odd that you have a `timestamp(4)` column, which is very precise, and can match back exactly an hour; though so far values haven't needed that kind of precision.